# How can I customise Yandex maps api controls?

Tags: javascript, html, css, yandex-maps

I need to customise Yandex maps api controls, but I don't know how to do it directly by customising embedded api classes like ymaps-2-1-76-map... So can I customise controls like resize buttons somehow different and how? 
[What styles i try to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLJa1.png)

Answer (score 1):

The Yandex.Maps API documentation has an example of customizing controls:
https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsbox/2.1/zoom_layout

In the same documentation there is an example of a hint with rounding corners.
https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_hint_layout

By combining these two examples, you can get what you have in mind.